# Selenium - How to check that a text is present in an element?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

**HTML:**

```
<span class="A" style="color: rgb(10, 133, 154);">3 </span>
```

**Selenium:**

```
var totalCount = await driver.findElement(By.css(".A")).getText();
```

**Scenario:**

1. In Selenium, I have written a code to store the value '3' into totalCount.
2. When I run the code, it is successful 5 out of 10 times.
3. For those times that it failed, the value returned to totalCount was "NaN !"
4. I have no idea why, but I think it is because the text ('3') is not loaded yet.

**What I want to do:**

1. Run a check to ensure that the text in the element is loaded before i store it into totalCount.
2. The closest i could find here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html
   is elementTextContains().

**Question:**

1. What can i put in the substring argument of 'elementTextContains(element,substring)' to denote that as long as there is a text, the code can continue?
2. Is there another function that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: If you know what text can be, then you can use Regex

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with explicit wait ?

```
let ele = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('A')) , 10000);
let foo = await ele.getText();
```

> Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative,
> procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution,
> or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The
> condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the
> wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns
> a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

..

> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they
> make a good fit for synchronising the state between the browser and
> its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

[Official reference](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: I'll give it a go and try it out.